# I am having troubles with my for loop matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having troubles with my for loop in my code.  My code is the card game of war and is scored by, 1 point per round won and 2 points per war won. The problems that I am having are when player 1 wins a round it adds a point to both players and when you get the 20 points to win the program doesn't tell who wins, it just restarts.

```
player_1_name = input('Enter player 1`s name ','s');
player_2_name = input('Enter player 2`s name ','s');
clc
fprintf('Hello %s and %s!\n Welcome to my version of the card game of War.\n   Here are some rules to get you started:\n 1)The first person to 20 points wins. \n 2)You will win 1 point for winning a round and 2 points for winning a war. \n 3)The jack is represented as an 11, \n the queen is represented as a 12, \n the king is represented as a 13, \n and the ace is represented as a 14. \n 4)Remember to have fun!\n',player_1_name,player_2_name)
disp('Press enter when you are ready to begin! ')

pause
clc
A = repmat(2:14, [1, 4]);
shuffled_deck = A(randperm(length(A)));
disp('Ok, lets get started!')
fprintf('Dealing out %s`s and %s`s hands. \n',player_1_name,player_2_name)
pause(5)
disp('The hands are dealt.')
disp('Now we are ready to start!')
disp('Press enter when you are ready to begin. ')
player1_hand = shuffled_deck(1:26);
player2_hand = shuffled_deck(27:52);
pause
clc
T = 10;
J = 11;
Q = 12;
K = 13;
A = 14;

n1= 0;
n2 = 0;


 for n1 = 0:20
 for n2 = 0:20
     fprintf('\n %s has %2.0f points. \n ',player_1_name,n1)
     fprintf('%s has %2.0f points. ',player_2_name,n2)
     pause
     clc
     disp('Lets draw cards! ')
     disp('3....2....1...DRAW!' )
    pause

 player_1_card = randsample(player1_hand,1);
 fprintf('%s drew a %2.0f. ',player_1_name,player_1_card)
 pause
 player_2_card = randsample(player2_hand,1);
 fprintf('%s drew a %2.0f. \n',player_2_name,player_2_card)
 pause

 if player_1_card > player_2_card;
    n1 = n1+1;
    fprintf('%s wins this round and wins one point! \n',player_1_name)
 elseif player_1_card < player_2_card;
     n2 = n2+1;
     fprintf('%s wins this round and wins one point! \n',player_2_name)
 else player_1_card = player_2_card;
     display('War!')
     x2 = randsample(player1_hand,1);
     x3 = randsample(player1_hand,1);
     x4 = randsample(player1_hand,1);
     x5 = randsample(player1_hand,1);
     x6 = randsample(player2_hand,1);
     x7 = randsample(player2_hand,1);
     x8 = randsample(player2_hand,1);
     x9 = randsample(player2_hand,1);
     fprintf('%s drew a%2.0f, a%2.0f, a%2.0f, and a%2.0f. \n',player_1_name,x2,x3,x4,x5)
     fprintf('%s drew a%2.0f, a%2.0f, a%2.0f, and a%2.0f. \n',player_2_name,x6,x7,x8,x9)

       if x5 > x9;
         n1 = n1 + 2;
         fprintf('%s wins this war and wins two points! \n',player_1_name)
            else x5 < x9;
         n2 = n2 + 2;
        fprintf('%s wins this war and wins two points! \n' ,player_2_name)
       end
 end
  a =  input(' \nPress 1 to play another hand. \n Press 2 to restart the game. \n Press 3 to end the game. ');

 if a == 1;
 continue
 elseif a == 2;
     clc
     run('C:\Users\Derek\Documents\MATLAB\Week 12\warimproved.m')
 else a == 3;
   return 
 end
 end
end


 if n1 >= 20
fprintf('%s wins ', player_1_name)
return
elseif n2 >= 20
fprintf('%s wins ', player_2_name)
return
 else
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're running it in a dual for loop - for loops automatically increment the variables they are iterating over. If you remove that and instead use a single while loop, i.e. remove `for n1 = 0:20` and `for n2 = 0:20` and insert `while (n1 < 20 && n2 < 20)`, your program works as intended. You'll need to remove one `end`.